# IIS Application Recycle drops static classes

Tags: wcf, iis, dependency-injection, dependencies, code-injection

I'm using Simple Injector in my WCF service. While running it from VS2010 everything is fine. However, when I publish it to my server using IIS 7, after some time (20 min, counted) my WCF loses all registered assemblies, modules, classes in container.

I guess IIS recycles the WCF Service Application Pool and drops my container registrations.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: For any serious work, I would recommend to **self-host** any WCF services - exactly for this reason, hosting in IIS doesn't give you full control over what's happening.

Comment: See [Self-Hosting WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx) - or just search on Google or Bing ....

Answer (score 1):

While there exists many legitimate cases of using self-hosting WCF services, however, approaching self-hosting just because of IIS recycling may be counter productive.

Hosting in IIS gives you a lot benefit during development and daily operations, and I am not going to repeat what benefits which you could easily find out in google search.

So when IIS receive the first request to your application, it will launch a worker process named "w3wp.exe" according the settings in the application pool associated with your web app. And by default IIS will shutdown in 20 minutes of idle time. Check the Advanced Settings of the application pool, you will find a lot settings for the life cycle. You won't get such flexibility and robustness through self-hosting out of the box.

So basically you could have a few options provided you decide to stay with IIS hosting.

1. Change the Idle Time-out to 24-hours or even a month.
2. Write a small program or use cUrl to ping your application every 10 minute.
3. Leave it as it is
4. If you want to keep states during operations, save them in disk, then load them during next launch triggered by a request.

Comment: I don't think the OP minds that IIS recycles the application, but the problem he is experiencing is that after a certain time window, his service stops functioning, because after that time it seems that his application state is cleared, while the WCF startup code isn't called again.